# Changing symbol in quantmod code

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following code that creates a stock chart using data from Yahoo using the R package quantmod.  The symbol retrieved in the code is "KR" in my example.

How can I change the code so that I can retrieve other stock symbols without having to replace each incidence of "KR" with the new stock symbol?

```
library(quantmod) 
library(TTR)


getSymbols("KR",  src="yahoo")
KR <- adjustOHLC(KR, use.Adjusted=TRUE)

KR.EMA.9<- EMA(KR$KR.Close, n=5) 
KR.EMA.34<- EMA(KR$KR.Close, n=50) 
KR.EMA.200 <- EMA(KR$KR.Close, n=200)


candleChart(KR, theme="white", 
            subset='2015-09::2015-10')
            addTA(KR.EMA.9, on=1, col = "red")
            addTA(KR.EMA.34, on=1, col = "blue")
            addTA(KR.EMA.9 - KR.EMA.34,col='blue', type='h',legend="9-34 MA")
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the option `auto.assign=FALSE`. Here's an example.

```
library(quantmod)
my_tickers  <- c("KR","AAPL", "MSFT") #store the tickers in a vector
my_xts <- getSymbols(my_tickers[1],  src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)
tail(my_xts)
#           KR.Open KR.High KR.Low KR.Close KR.Volume KR.Adjusted
#2016-03-16   37.87   38.69  37.82    38.61   6208100       38.61
#2016-03-17   38.45   38.56  37.98    38.09   9445400       38.09
#2016-03-18   38.14   38.88  38.00    38.56   9809000       38.56
#2016-03-21   38.38   38.60  38.09    38.13   5911400       38.13
#2016-03-22   38.18   38.32  37.69    37.95   7988000       37.95
#2016-03-23   37.92   38.02  37.35    37.59   9089000       37.59
```

The same code can be used to select another ticker by just changing the index of `my_tickers[]`:

```
my_xts <- getSymbols(my_tickers[2],  src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)
tail(my_xts)
#           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
#2016-03-16    104.61    106.31   104.59     105.97    37893800        105.97
#2016-03-17    105.52    106.47   104.96     105.80    34244600        105.80
#2016-03-18    106.34    106.50   105.19     105.92    43402300        105.92
#2016-03-21    105.93    107.65   105.14     105.91    35180800        105.91
#2016-03-22    105.25    107.29   105.21     106.72    32232600        106.72
#2016-03-23    106.48    107.07   105.90     106.13    25452600        106.13
```

Therefore the code could be run, for example, with a loop of the type

```
for (i in 1:length(my_tickers)) {
  my_xts <- getSymbols(my_tickers[i],  src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)
  # perform analysis of the time series my_xts here
}
```

The closing price can be selected using `Cl()` (there are corresponding functions to select other columns, see `?OHLC.Transformations` for more details).

It is thereby possible to calculate the EMA and other indicators based on the close data like this:

```
EMA.9 <- EMA(Cl(my_xts), 9)
tail(EMA.9)
#                EMA
#2016-03-16 102.6959
#2016-03-17 103.3167
#2016-03-18 103.8374
#2016-03-21 104.2519
#2016-03-22 104.7455
#2016-03-23 105.0224
```